# Easier opening of Windows with one Void

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a Launcher for my Software I'm trying to develop. Now the settings have a "Persistent Window" so the launcher does stay open or not after selecting one of it's buttons.

Now I want to simplify the window generation process with on private void in the same class. But I don't know how I give the void the needed window

this is the Project-Structure:

[image]

I've tried it with several Types of arguments for the call like "string, Window or type" but every time I'm getting:

> "xxx is a variable but it used as Type"

This is the button-code which calls the future window

```
        private void Btn_NewAdress_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
             fun_openWindow(Adress.frm_Adress,"new");
        }
```

And this is the new void I created:

```
        private void fun_openWindow(Window selectedWindow, string type)
        {
            selectedWindow form = new selectedWindow();
            form.Show();

            switch (type)
            {
                case "search":
                    form.ti_search.IsSelected = true;
                    break;
                default:
                    form.ti_new.IsSelected = true;
                    break;
            }

            if (Properties.Settings.Default.persistentWindow == true)
            {
                this.Close();
            }
        }
```

I want that the window I write into the argument will open and if the settings are set, the launcher should close or not.

Comment: What is `frm_Adress`?

Comment: What is Adress? (please read [mcve])

Comment: frm adress is a Window (WPF) with "public partial class frm_Adress : Window" and the publig initializecomponent()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generic for it:

```
private void Btn_NewAdress_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    fun_openWindow<Adress.frm_Adress>("new");
}
private void fun_openWindow<YourWindow>(string type) where YourWindow: Window, new()
{
    YourWindow form = new YourWindow();
    form.Show();
}
```

Another way is to use reflection:

```
private void Btn_NewAdress_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    fun_openWindow(typeof(Adress.frm_Adress), "new");
}
private void fun_openWindow(Type frmType, string type)
{
    var form = Activator.CreateInstance(frmType) as Window;
    form.Show();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. But after the creation of the form (`form.show()`) is there a way to access the formelements of the new forms? so that the switch-case from above works? 
Now I'm getting "`Window does not contain a definition "ti_search"`which is in the switch case

Comment: You can try e.g. to use `((CustomWindowTypeWithProperties)form).ti_search.IsSelected = true;` in `switch` statement, to cast your object to definite type.

Comment: Sorry, i don't get it somehow, even that you are describing it that good. `CustomWindowTypeWithProperties` what exactly does it have to be written there?

Comment: A class/type, which contains `ti_search`.

Comment: But `Adress.frm_Adress` contains ti_search, or the other forms wich i try to open with this function, so like the content from the first attribute. And then it's a Variable which is used like a type.

Answer (score 1):

The error

> selectedWindow is a variable but is used as type

is correct, because you are indeed using your variable `selectedWindow` as a type.

The error is likely to occur in the following line of code:

```
selectedWindow form = new selectedWindow();
```

On the left side of the assignment, the compiler expects a type and then a variable name. 
In your case you have specified a variable name (`selectedWindow`) and then another variable name (`form`). 
Furthermore, on the right side of the assignment the compiler expects the keyword `new` and a type (for example the type of your window), but you specified the variable name (`selectedWindow`) instead of a valid type.
The correct syntax would be:

```
Window form = new YourWindowClass();
```

For your implementation the `YourWindowClass` is either `frm_Adress` or `frm_Launcher` depending of the window shown.